# oracle long to number conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to get the name of the current partition from all_tab_partitions table. When i try to compare high_value (long data Type) and number. It throws an error:

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_OWNER='SCHEMA_NAM'
AND TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'
AND HIGH_VALUE>to_number(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), 'MONTH'), 'YYYYDDD'))
/
```

Comment: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Answer (score 7):

Long type stores large variable lenght character strings, it is NOT a numeric type. It has many limitations. Oracle documentation says:

The use of LONG values is subject to these restrictions:

- A table can contain only one LONG column.
- You cannot create an object type with a LONG attribute.
- **LONG columns cannot appear in WHERE** or in integrity constraints (except that they can appear in and NOT NULL constraints).
- LONG columns cannot be indexed.
- LONG cannot be specified in regular expressions.
- A stored function return a LONG value.
- You can declare a variable or argument of PL/SQL program unit using the LONG datatype. However, you cannot call the program unit from SQL.
- Within a single SQL statement, LONG columns, updated tables, and locked tables must be located the same database. LONG and LONG RAW columns cannot be used in distributed SQL statements and cannot be replicated.
- If a table has both LONG and LOB columns, then you cannot bind more than 4000 bytes of data to both the LONG and LOB columns in the same SQL statement. However, you can bind more than 4000 bytes of data to either the LONG or the LOB column.

Answer (score 6):

In order to examine or use the value of a LONG column you'll have to write some PL/SQL, similar to

```
DECLARE
  strHigh_value  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
                 FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
                 WHERE TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAM' AND
                       TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME')
  LOOP
    strHigh_value := aRow.HIGH_VALUE;

    -- TODO: Manipulate strHigh_value in whatever manner you need

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write any PL/SQL try to use (in general case):

```
select 
    sys.dbms_metadata_util.long2varchar(4000, 'TABLE_NAME', 'COLUMN_NAME', tp.rowid) as COLUMN_NAME 
from 
   TABLE_NAME tp 
where 
   <your_condition on table TABLE_NAME>
```

don't use COLUMN_NAME in ...your_condition on table TABLE_NAME...

In your case it's a bit more complicated because you query a VIEW.
It's necessary to dig in the view code and rewrite your query as:

```
select PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE from (
    select t.PARTITION_NAME, sys.dbms_metadata_util.long2varchar(4000, 'SYS.TABCOMPART$', 'HIBOUNDVAL', tp.rowid) as high_value
    from 
        all_tab_partitions t, sys.obj$ o, sys.tabcompart$ tp
    where 
        t.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
        and t.table_owner = 'SCHEMA_NAM'
        and o.name = t.table_name
        and o.subname = t.partition_name
        and o.obj# = tp.obj#(+)
)
where 
    high_value > to_number(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), 'MONTH'), 'YYYYDDD'))
```

tested on Oracle 11g